# Java Reg ex to check the given value length

Tags: java, regex, is-empty

I am using the following reg ex to validate whether the given value's length is more than zero

```
Regex :   .*\S.*; 

value : test
```

and this the method i use to test :

```
public boolean isValidInput(String pattern, String value) {
        boolean isValid = false;
        Pattern walletInputPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher walletMatcher = walletInputPattern.matcher(value);
        if (walletMatcher.matches()) {
            isValid = true;
        }
        return isValid;
    }
```

but it returns `false`

```
desired output
```

1. check the given value whether it is not empty and at least has one value.

Thanks

Comment: I may be missing something here but why are you using a regex to see if a String is empty?

Comment: Why would you use a regex in the first place ? Anyways, in Java you need to escape the backslash, so your regex becomes `.*\\S.*`. You could just use `[\\S\\s]`

Answer (score 1):

Why not this simple approach?

```
public boolean isValidInput(String pattern, String value) {
    return value != null && value.trim().length() > 0;
}
```

Comment: Can be simplified to `return value != null && value.trim().length() > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Regex because I don't only check for not empty or length is greater than zero with string I have so many other which uses the same method I provided.

the answer for above question is : `^(?=\\s*\\S).*$`